# Visual Studio Installer: Copy File On Finish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment-project

i have a C# project, it's finished now and i need to make an installer for it.
I added the Setup and Deployment Project and listed all the needed prerequisites, now i just need to copy the database file when the installation finishes.

Just a simple "create a folder named /db/" (in the installation folder) and copy the db.mdf in it.

I'm googleing but i can't find anything i could use.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the reference documentation: [How to: Add and Remove Files in the File System Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a1ww3t8.aspx) ?

This is typically how you can do it. You can also create folders in there, but note you can have some limitations (with .MSI, you are not supposed to create folder anywhere on the target's disk).